# Locating a .CSR in Windows Server 2019

Tags: networking, certificate, ssl-certificate, ca

I work as a technician for a school in Southern Ohio and recently one of our CA's expired bricking the wireless. I am looking for any possible way to compile a list of all .csr files within Win Server 2019. The previous technical administrator left a mess for us to clean up so we can't use the locate command and none of his documentation denotes any information regarding its name or location. Looking forward to hearing from people as this is my first time posting to StackOverflow. Thank you all for your participation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PowerShell's `foreach($request in Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\" -Filer "*.csr"){ & certutil -dump $_; }` to list all *.csr-files and `certutil.exe -dump` to process/view them.